# How to fix close to json with php

Tags: php, jquery, json

A follow up to: https://stackoverflow.com/posts/13303108 where all the responses suggested JS

Is there a function of some sort to take the following and fix it with php when it occurs so that the output will be vaild json? front end (js) is not an option. The issue seems to be the number leading into the array not being quoted or something to that end. I cannot fix the source either.

```
 {
    29646191: [
        "https://www.facebook.com/RobertScoble/posts/480030845352725",
        "https://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg",
        "Today I tried... | Facebook",
        "Robert Scoble wrote: Today I tried something. I paid $49 and... Join Facebook to connect with Robert Scoble and others you may know.",
        null,
        [
            "//images3-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003da\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026refresh\u003d31536000\u0026resize_h\u003d150\u0026resize_w\u003d150\u0026no_expand\u003d1",
            150,
            150,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            null,
            [
                3,
                "https://images1-focus-opensocial.googleusercontent.com/gadgets/proxy?url\u003dhttps://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-prn1/s480x480/546943_10151235934049655_1771118951_n.jpg\u0026container\u003dfocus\u0026gadget\u003dhttps://plus.google.com\u0026rewriteMime\u003dimage/*\u0026resize_h\u003d800\u0026resize_w\u003d800\u0026no_expand\u003d1"
            ]
        ],
        "//s2.googleusercontent.com/s2/favicons?domain\u003dwww.facebook.com",
        [],
        null,
        []
    ]
}
```

Edit: the very base functions do not work here (json encode/decode). It had to have been taken from a source and run through many things for php to even start to be able to handle it.

To wit, this is the code that handles it before this

```
       $instring = false;
    $inescape = false;
    $lastchar = '';
    $output = "";
    for ( $x=0; $x<strlen( $sourcejson ); $x++ ) {

        $char = substr( $sourcejson, $x, 1 );

        //toss unnecessary whitespace
        if ( !$instring && ( preg_match( '/\s/', $char ) ) ) {
            continue;
        }

        //handle strings
        if ( $instring ) {
            if ( $inescape ) {
                $output .= $char;
                $inescape = false;
            } else if ( $char == '\\' ) {
                $output .= $char;
                $inescape = true;
            } else if ( $char == '"' ) {
                $output .= $char;
                $instring = false;
            } else {
                $output .= $char;
            }
            $lastchar = $char;
            continue;
        }


        switch ( $char ) {

            case '"':
                $output .= $char;
                $instring = true;
                break;

            case ',':
                if ( $lastchar == ',' || $lastchar == '[' || $lastchar == '{' ) { 
                    $output .= 'null';
                }
                $output .= $char;
                break;

            case ']':
            case '}':
                if ( $lastchar == ',' ) { 
                    $output .= 'null';
                }
                $output .= $char;
                break;

            default:
                $output .= $char;
                break;
        }
        $lastchar = $char;
    }
```

Comment: why aren't u using `json_decode`, `json_decode`?

Comment: I am, its not seen.. i am using json_decode($output,true) to try and deal with it, and then put in db, but I cant get it to said point.

Answer (score 1):

Do not try to encode/decode json on your own.

To encode json from a PHP array:

```
echo json_encode($data);
```

To decode json:

```
var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

In your case, you need to convert the INT to a String. Try this:

```
# this solution requires PHP >= 5.4.0
var_dump(json_decode($data, false, 512, JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING));
```

See [**`json_decode()`**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php) for more information

---

### EDIT

If this still isn't working for you, I'd highly consider get valid JSON in JavaScript before processing it with your PHP script.

```js
// sadly this is the only solution i can find; luckily, your json is coming from a trusted source (Google), so eval shouldn't be an issue;
jsonObject = eval('(' + invalidJsonString + ')');

// conver the object back to json string
validJsonString = JSON.stringify(jsonObject);

// yay, valid json
console.log(validJsonString);
```

[**See it working on jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/8XBnX/)

### Disclaimer

Normally you'd use `jQuery.parseJSON(jsonString)` or `JSON.parse(jsonString`, but these are giving a parse error with that int as a key in the object :(

Comment: I am going to try the "in your case" but as it seems to be the best answer so far, have an upvote.

Comment: Well take a look at the documentation regarding `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING`; it's describing your case to a T :)

Comment: Sadly, `JSON_BIGINT_AS_STRING` requires PHP >= 5.4.0 :S

Comment: Note, I could probably find a non-eval solution for you if you show me the code you're using to actually get the JSON.

Comment: I would love to, I believe i have added your gmail for chat, I cannot share the entire thing publicly.

Comment: I have tried these, and none of them help
$output = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)/', '\\1:"\\2"', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/:(\d+)/', ':"${1}"', $output);
$output = preg_replace('/("\w+"):(\d+)(.\d+)?/', '\\1:"\\2\\3"', $output);

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20054/discussion-between-jay-and-macek)

Answer (score 0):

you should use the `json_decode();`

try this

```
$data[] = //some json;
 var_dump(json_decode($data));
```

then you can use

```
json_last_error()
```

to check eventual errors

see the reference doc: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.json-decode.php